# How to copy odoo website files to different web server?

Tags: webserver, odoo

Good Evening,,

Odoo Site Builder is very useful tool for building a dynamic, responsive, beautiful and easy website, so i want to use Odoo as a website builder for building websites and copy it to another web servers.

Where is the directory of Odoo v8 website files?

Thx for the help.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not easy. You cannot just transfer Odoo files to another web server and run it. The Odoo SIte Builder is inside the `website` module. The module relies heavily on the base of Odoo, working with other modules. So I thinks it's overkill.

Comment: Ok @macdelacruz
Thanx for the help

Comment: @DieterMeemken  
Copied this path into another server
~odoo/addons/website/static

But I think macdelacruz is right, and it is not that easy, it need a full module to perform this action on the odoo server, then copy it to another servers. 
Thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Install odoo on the device that you want to copy your data in.

then copy all files in Odoo\server\openerp\addons to the other computer.